# Stretch tabular vertically inside a column of multicol environment

Tags: tables, multicol

I have an a3 paper with a 3 column-layout using the `multicol` package and I have put tables on each column. I would like the tables to stretch out vertically - meaning that the space between rows increase - in order to fill the column up entirely. An extra condition I would like to set is that the tables do not move over to other columns (breaks defined by `\columnbreak`). Below I have provided some example code. I have turned on the `showframe` option for the `geometry` package to provide a reference line.

**Code**

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[centering, showframe, landscape, a3paper, margin = 1cm, top = 0.75cm, bottom = 0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{1.2em}}
\newenvironment{Group}
        {\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth-0.5cm}{@{}NXr}}
        {\endtabularx
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\raggedcolumns
\interlinepenalty=10000

% First column
\input{mwe.tex}
\input{mwe.tex}

\columnbreak

% % Second column
\begin{Group}
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 
\end{Group}

\vspace{1cm}

\input{mwe.tex}

\vspace{0.5cm} % not sure why this can't be 1cm without everything moving, space seems to be there.

\input{mwe.tex}


\columnbreak

% % Third column
\begin{Group}
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 
\end{Group}

\columnbreak
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

mwe.tex

```
\begin{Group}
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 
\end{Group}
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the sample code to describe my problem better, and also provided an image of the current situation[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow stretch-ability between rows in a table if the table is created directly by the TeX primitive `\halign` because this primitive creates rows and puts them into outer vertical list without encapsulating them into another boxes.

My example below creates two columns with height `\heightofcolumn` and width `\widthofcolumn`. First of them includes three tables, 1cm between them. Second column includes only two tables, so there must be more stretched baselineskip. The box concept at primitive level is:

```
\hbox{<column> <kern> <column>}
```

and each `<column>` is

```
\vbox to\heighofcolumn{<initialization> <material>}
```

The whole example looks like this:

```
\newdimen\heightofcolumn \heightofcolumn=7cm % for testing purpose
\newdimen\widthofcolumn \widthofcolumn=7cm

\long\def\column#1{%
   \vbox to\heightofcolumn{
       \hsize=\widthofcolumn 
       \baselineskip=\dimexpr\baselineskip plus3em minus5pt
       \kern\topskip
       \hbox to\widthofcolumn {}
       \vskip-\baselineskip
       #1\par
   }%
}

\hbox{%
   \column{  % first column
       \halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\cr % qeuivalent to tabular{lr}
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum  \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ip    & Lorem ipsum Lorem \cr
       }
       \vskip 1cm
       \halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\cr % equivalent to tabular{lr}
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum  \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ip    & Lorem ipsum Lorem \cr
       }
       \vskip 1cm
       \halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\cr % equivalent to tabular{lr}
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum  \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ip    & Lorem ipsum Lorem \cr
       }
   }%
   \kern2em  % space between columns
   \column {  % second column
       \halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\cr % equivalent to tabular{lr}
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum  \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ip    & Lorem ipsum Lorem \cr
       }
       \vskip 2cm
       \halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\cr % equivalent to tabular{lr}
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum  \cr
           Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum L \cr
           Lorem ip    & Lorem ipsum Lorem \cr
       }
   }%
}
```

Note the line

```
\baselineskip=\dimexpr\baselineskip plus3em minus5pt
```

this gives stretch-ability and shrink-ability between rows. The other commands in the initialization take care of the correct placement of the first row in the column.

**Edit** If we know the width of table cells then we need not to use `\halign` primitive nor a macro based on `\halign`. We can construct the rows like

```
 \hbox to\hsize{<box> <text> <box>}
```

where `<box>` is `\hbox to<given-dimen>{...}` and `<text>` is a text which includes a stretch-able glue (`\dotfill` in your example).
I created the macro `\r` which creates single row with given parameters. The whole example is here:

```
\newdimen\heightofcolumn \heightofcolumn=7cm
\newdimen\widthofcolumn \widthofcolumn=7cm

\def\r #1&#2&#3\\{\hbox to\hsize{%
   \hbox to1.5em{#1\hss}\ignorespaces#2\unskip\hbox to3em{\hss#3\unskip}%
}}

\long\def\column#1{%
   \vbox to\heightofcolumn{
       \hsize=\widthofcolumn
       \baselineskip=\dimexpr\baselineskip plus3em minus5pt
       \kern\topskip
       \hbox to\widthofcolumn {}
       \vskip-\baselineskip
       #1\par
   }%
}

\hbox{%
   \column{
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
       \r 2 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 20.00 \\
       \r 3 & Lorem ipsum Lorem  \dotfill € & 30.00 \\
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum \dotfill € & 40.00 \\
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem psum \dotfill € & 110.00 \\
       \r 13 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 210.00 \\
       \vskip 1cm
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
       \r 2 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 20.00 \\
       \vskip 1cm
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
       \r 2 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 20.00 \\
       \r 3 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 30.00 \\
       \r 4 & Lorem ipsum L \dotfill € & 40.00 \\
  }%
   \kern2em  % space between columns
   \column {
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
       \r 2 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 20.00 \\
       \r 3 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 30.00 \\
       \vskip 2cm
       \r 1 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 10.00 \\
       \r 2 & Lorem ipsum Lo \dotfill € & 20.00 \\
       \r 3 & Lorem ipsum Lorem \dotfill € & 30.00 \\
       \r 4 & Lorem ipsum L \dotfill € & 40.00 \\
   }%
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I noticed that I did forget a perhaps crucial part of my tables. In the sample code the tables are using left-aligned and right-aligned columns, but in my actual code I am using a `tabularx` environment with self-defined column 'types' with pre-defined lengths. Does that fit into the halign solution?

Comment: If all columns have given width then we needn't `\halign` at all, because each row is `\hbox` which includes `\hbox to...{...}` or `\vtop{\hsize=...}`. What exactly your tables look like?

Comment: In total I have three columns: \newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{1.2em}} is the first one. The second one uses the `X` notation which I believe means its size depends on the widths of the other columns. The last one is simply right-aligned. I presume the `X` column could also be written as the total length of a column (in context of column of an hbox)? Also for my own tabular environment I have set a table width of `\linewidth - 0.5cm`. Is it possible to have these dimensions taken into account?

Comment: It should be better and more clear if you add the exact example of such tables in your question text. Sorry, I am not able to imagine your tables only from such descriptions.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, that is on me for not being concise. I have tried to provide better sample code now!

Comment: @PLY OK, I added a new part of my answer.